# Go back to previous pop up in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement to open a pop on click on a actionlink in MVC. It is working fine. 
Main Page (hyperLink)--> Opens a div as popup (1st Popup) (hyperlink)--> Opens another popup (2nd Popup)

Everything is working fine, My problem is on click of a button in 2nd popup it should close the second popup and go back to first popup(it should display as a popup not as a new window)

I have tried windows.open and windows.location. Either it is opening in a new tab or the 2nd pop is not closing and there are so many popups in the page.

Any way to resolve this?

Updated:

Main Page Code to open a popup:
Javasript:

```
 $(function () {
    $('#CreateLink').click(function () {
        debugger;
        $.get(this.href, function (result) {
            debugger;
            var div = $("#DivToAppendPartialView");
            div.load("/ControllerName/PopUp1", { Param1: ""});
            div.dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 550,
                height: 500,
                title: "Add New",
                resizable: false,
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});

I have a empty div in Main Page:
 @Html.ActionLink("Create","Create","ControllerName",new {@id="CreateLink"})
<div id="DivToAppendPartialView">
```

In the 1st Popup I have the following code to open the second PopUp
 An empty div

```
<div id="DivAddlFields" style="overflow: hidden;"></div><a href="#"id="CreateAddlField">Add Fields</a>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(function () {
    $('#CreateAddlField').click(function () {
        debugger;

        var Param3 = "CreateNewRule";
        var Param2 = $("#Param1").val();
        debugger;
        var div2 = $("#DivAddlFields");

        div2.load("/ControllerName/PopUp2", { Param1: 0, Param2: Param2, Param3: Param3 }),

            div2.dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 600,
                height: 600,
                title: "Add Fields",
                resizable: false,
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    location.reload();
                }

            });

    });
});

This opens the second PopUp.

In Second Pop i have this button, on click of this button i want to close the second popup and open the first popup

 <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddFields()" id="btnAddFields" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to share some code and describe it, if you are expecting any solution.

Comment: Added some code, please do let me know if some more explanation is needed